# HTTPS with ESP8266WebServer?

Tags: esp8266, web-server, http

I see many ESP8266HTTPClient examples, pasting in a fingerprint from an outside website, but I want to *host* an html page from the ESP8266 in AP mode using HTTPS.

Judging by the lack of examples, and the lack of a domain for a cert in AP mode, I'm thinking this is impossible, but would like confirmation before I give up.

Is it impossible to get the browser's green padlock on an AP-served web page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ESP8266 just doesn't have sufficient CPU power to do this reliably.

It is possible, since the EPS8266 SDK docs have an "[SSL User Manual](http://wiki.ai-thinker.com/_media/esp8266/docs/5a-esp8266_sdk_ssl_user_manual_en_v1.4.pdf)" which describes this scenario.

In my experience, using the Arduino core for ESP8266, it doesn't work reliably.

Consider using an `nginx` reverse-proxy and having that proxy handle SSL negotiation. Understand that this is more for situations where the ESP8266 is local, in a network sense, to the nginx proxy, and you consider your WLAN secure enough.

On the plus side, you have room to grow in key sizes and/or complexity.

Comment: thanks for the link, that does help. sadly it's not the arduino core, but i guess i could use 2 ESPs, pretending one's an arduino like the noobs setup...